# string.includes('a') function not defined in Node.js 0.12?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I do understand the includes() array-function is only supported for ECMAscript 6+, but isn't ECMAscript 6 now already supported in Node.js? I've also tried to run:

```
node --harmony app.js
```

but that gave me an:

```
node: bad option: --harmony
```

On my Windows 8 machine.

I've also tried to use string.contains('a'); but that array-function isn't defined as well.

Comment: what version of node are using?

Comment: `'foo'.contains()` works just fine on node v0.12.2 with `node --harmony`. It also works on io.js *without* any flags, but there it is `'foo'.includes()`. The name changed from `contains()` to `includes()` between the v8 versions used by node 0.12 and io.js.

Comment: Version: 12.4 on Windows, but I can't get 'foo'.contains() work without --harmoney, it says "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.prototype.includes` is available in Node as `String.prototype.contains`. Check this out:  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. Look at the flag 26. 
I think, originally the name proposed in the standard was `contains` but then it has been changed due to compatibility issues.

V8 Pull Request : https://codereview.chromium.org/742963002

You can check what options are supported by your node version by using `node --v8-options | grep harm`. Make sure you're using an update version of node.

This is the output for node version 0.12.2

```
Giuseppes-Air:development giuseppe$ node --v8-options | grep harm
  --harmony_scoping (enable harmony block scoping)
  --harmony_modules (enable harmony modules (implies block scoping))
  --harmony_proxies (enable harmony proxies)
  --harmony_generators (enable harmony generators)
  --harmony_numeric_literals (enable harmony numeric literals (0o77, 0b11))
  --harmony_strings (enable harmony string)
  --harmony_arrays (enable harmony arrays)
  --harmony_arrow_functions (enable harmony arrow functions)
  --harmony (enable all harmony features (except proxies))
```

As you can see from the output, arrow strings ( => ), strings and array are enabled when the `harmony` option is used.

If you want to fully enjoy ES6, I would suggest to use `babel` and `babel-node`. `String.prototype.includes` is correctly supported.

Comment: are you referring to `node --v8-options`? if so, it should work. If you are in windows, you don't have grep.

Comment: @Kil'jaeden `node --v8-options` returns the list of features supported by the v8 version node is using. Each line tells you if that particular feature is enable by default and its type.